# bottle.py render static file

Tags: python, bottle

I'm building a bottle.py app that grabs some data from MongoDB and renders it into a web page using pygal.

The code produces a `Error: 500 Internal Server Error` in my browser.

On the server, I see: `Exception: TypeError('serve_static() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)',)`.

My question: how do I correct the code to render the `.svg` file?

The code:

```
import sys
import bottle
from bottle import get, post, request, route, run, static_file
import pymongo
import json
import pygal

connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost", safe=True)

@get('/chart')  
def serve_static(chart):
    db = connection.control
    chart = db.chart
    cursor = chart.find({}, {"num":1, "x":1, "_id":0})
    data = []
    for doc in cursor:
        data.append(doc)
    list = [int(i.get('x')) for i in data]
    line = pygal.Line()
    line.title = 'widget quality'
    line.x_labels = map(str, range(1, 20))
    line.add('quality measure', list)
    line.render_to_file('chart.svg')
    try:
        return static_file(chart.svg, root='/home/johnk/Desktop/chart/',mimetype='image/svg+xml')
    except:
        return "<p>Yikes! Somethin' wrong!</p>" 

bottle.debug(True)
bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give a parameter to the route, so the function doesn't get any.

What you probably want to do, is either:

```
@get('/<chart>')  
def serve_static(chart):
    ...
```

If you want `/myfile.svg` to work, or:

```
@get('/chart/<chart>')  
def serve_static(chart):
    ...
```

If you want `/chart/myfile.svg` to work.

If you just want to show the same SVG file every time, you can just leave off the parameter:

```
@get('/chart')
def serve_static():
    ...
```